# Azure CI (YAML) pipe is failing on task SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1 with SqlPackage.exe exited with code 1

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines

I have a database project that is being deployed to an Azure SQL Database instance. This CI pipe was working in another environment outside the organization. We lift/shifted it into this organization. The job that is failing is a deployment job. The task that is used is `SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1`.

**Error message:**

> ##[error]*** An unexpected failure occurred: One or more errors occurred..

> ##[error]The Azure SQL DACPAC task failed. SqlPackage.exe exited with code 1.Check out how to troubleshoot failures at
> https://aka.ms/sqlazuredeployreadme#troubleshooting-

**Code:**

```
 - task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
   displayName: 'info...'
   inputs:
     azureSubscription: $(ServiceConnection)
     serverName: $(sqlServer)
     databaseName: $(DbName)
     SqlUsername: $(AdminAccount)
     SqlPassword: $(AdminAccountPassword)
     dacpacFile: '$(BuildName)\\db_name\\bin\\Output\\db_name.dacpac'
     publishProfile: '$(BuildName)$(publishProfile)'
```

The deployment task is using a combination of DACPAC and a publish profile. This is necessary due to extensive usage of SQLCMD variables. The agent is a self-hosted Windows agent. It has been updated. Each time a user defined capability was added the agent service was restarted.

1. I have validated the account and password by connecting to the target instance with both accounts.
2. I have tried authenticating with Azure Active Directory principals which are admins on the Azure SQL Database.
3. I tried using SQL Server authentication.
4. I have added a user defined capability to the Windows Self-hosted agent for SqlPackage with compatibility level 150 which matched the database compatibility level.
5. I tried reducing the database compatibility level from 150 to 130 to match the system define capability on the agent.
6. I verified that the directories structure matches the YAML and that the DACPAC and the publish profile exist.
7. I verified the values stored in pipe variables outside of the YAML.
8. I verified that the machine that runs the agent has a firewall rule enabled on the Azure SQL Database instance.

I am looking for a likewise task now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Service Principal instead of SQL Authentication to deploy the Azure SQL Database.

Refer: https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/03/11/automated-deployment-of-azure-sql-database-azure-sql-data-warehouse-through-azure-devops-via-service-principal-part-1/

https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/03/12/automated-deployment-of-azure-sql-database-azure-sql-data-warehouse-through-azure-devops-via-service-principal-part-2/

Also, remove the `publishProfile` option and instead provided project variables in this format:

`AdditionalArguments: /v:MyVariable=Y /v:Environment=TST`,

and this should work.

Your final YAML file should look like this:

```
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
        displayName: Deploy dacpac
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: $(ServiceConnection)
          ServerName: <server_name>
          DatabaseName: <database_name>
          DacpacFile: $(Pipeline.Workspace)\drop\MyDacpac.dacpac
          AdditionalArguments: /v:ResetStuff=Y /v:Environment=TST
          DeploymentAction: Publish
          AuthenticationType: servicePrincipal
```

Comment: It should work with SQL authentication. If i want to use a service principle i will. This worked in another environment. The issue is that I cannot diagnose the problem. I don't want tens of SQLCMD variables in the CI pipe and the project. The variables have to be in the project for it to build.